# Default chart size in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, charts, size, default

Is there an easy way to set a default size for all new charts created in Excel 2010?

I need them to be like 10,52cm for a bunch of users at the office, and I can't seem to find how to do this without using macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cant set the *default* chart size you can add a Event handler to modify any new charts (needs vba code though)
(This is a new event to Excel 2010)

Put this in the Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewChart(ByVal Ch As Chart)
    Ch.Parent.Height = 400
    Ch.Parent.Width = 600
End Sub
```

Note: this assumes you can add code to the workbook charts will be added to.  If you prefer, you can create an addin that includes code to handle all workbook events.  This would remove the need to have this code in all workbooks.